# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException....crash report

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get crash report error for my app. I use imported sqlite database in assets folder. What am I doing wrong? Here's the error from user crash report:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Kviz20Hard.nextQuestionGrad(Kviz20Hard.java:328)
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Kviz20Hard.access$1(Kviz20Hard.java:307)
at rs.androidaplikacije.zastaveigradovi.Kviz20Hard$2.run(Kviz20Hard.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's my question method from my game class:

```
private void nextQuestionGrad() {

         flag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         dodatnoPitanje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

            if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
            mDbHelper.createDatabase();
            }

            try{  

                mDbHelper.open(); 

                Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestDataGradovi(mCurrentID);
                c.moveToFirst();

                List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

                tacanOdg = c.getString(2);

                Collections.shuffle(labels);

                dodatnoPitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

                bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
                bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
                bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
                bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
                bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
                bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
                bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
                bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
                bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);

            }
            finally{   
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
     }
```

I get error on line:

```
labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
```

Here's my adapter class:

```
public class TestAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestData(String whereClause){
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
             return mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         }

     public Cursor getTestDataGradovi(long id){
            String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblGradovi WHERE _ID = " + id;
            return  mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        }

     public Cursor getTestDataValute(long id){
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblValute WHERE _ID = " + id;

             return mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

Your problem is that most likely your `c.moveToFirst()` method returned false (it indicates whether cursor is empty or not) and for this reason you are getting `Exception`

Whenever you're dealing with cursors always check returned value from `moveToFirst()` method that represents "handy" tool how to detect a validity of cursor with condition and wrap your "actions" to this condition:

```
List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();
if (c != null) {
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      // do your stuff
      ...
      labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
      labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
      labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
      labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));
      ...
   }
   else {
     // Cursor is empty
   }
}
else {
   // Cursor is null
}
```

**Note:** When you want to retrieve value from specific column(s) contained in Cursor i recommend you to use `getColumnIndex(<columnName>)` method to avoid "typo" and "indexing" problems. This is very good and efficient practise.

Comment: And what to do on Else part of your code, when the cursor is null? And what when the cursor is empty?

Comment: @marjanbaz show maybe some error message to logcat for you? then you know where is problem. If cursor is empty, probably your db doesn't contain data or specific row. If is `NULL`, problem is in `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: I just don't get why would the cursor be empty. I have exactly 197 rows with 6 columns. Every time I draw a random row.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `Cursor` data but it seems empty. use the `c.moveToFirst()` to actually check if the cursor is empty - it returns a boolean indication: `boolean isFilledWithData = c.moveToFirst()`

Comment: Do I declare this in my nextQuestionGrad() or as a class variable?